# Is there a way to simulate the presence of basic hardware (mouse, display) on GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, github, github-actions, display, pyautogui

I'm currently working on a Python project that relies on [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to take control of the mouse. I set up an ensemble of tests to run on my machine before pushing any new change to GitHub, but I would also like to set up a workflow on GitHub Actions to build and test my application on push.

But, as you can imagine, my problem is that the environment in which the tests are run on GitHub Actions has no screen nor mouse. My scripts only need to access the screen resolution (`width, height = pyautogui.size()`) and to perform simple actions (*e.g.* `pyautogui.click('left')`, `pyautogui.scroll(...)`). My tests don't actually require any window to pop-up to perform actions on them, just to be able to run these simple functions.

Currently, it seems that the issue is the lack of display:

```
[...]
    import pyautogui
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

as the `DISPLAY` environment variable does not exist (or perhaps is equal to `:0` due to the lack of display). I am not sure that the mouse is an issue yet, since it does not go beyond the display step, but I expect it to be problematic as well.

Does anyone know a way to simulate the presence of a screen and mouse on a GitHub Actions runner? Or any workaround?

Comment: There are virtual X servers that might let you automate these tests -- e.g., [Xephyr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xephyr).

Comment: If you don't want to simulate an actual display environment, you could write a mock version of `pyautogui` that's sufficient to drive your tests.

Comment: @larsks So I would just basically `apt install xserver-xephyr` and configure it before anything else in my workflow, and that would be it?

@Samwise OK, perhaps I should look into it.

Thank you both :)

Comment: Well, you would have to *start* it, also, and configure your DISPLAY environment to point at it, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I finally managed to get it working. I don't know anything about X servers, so it pretty much feels like a miracle.

To anyone interested, it simply comes down to installing and running `xvfb` **with** Python. Here's the critical part of my workflow:

```
[...]
    - name: Install
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install xvfb
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install .
        
    - name: Run tests
      run: |
        xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x8" python -m unittest discover -s tests
```

Python simply needs to be run on the same command as `xvfb-run`, and that's it. This sets the `DISPLAY` variable appropriately and solves the PyAutoGUI import that relies on it. Then, the mouse-related actions from PyAutoGUI execute without any problem, mouse or not.

Thanks for putting me on the right tracks.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

thanks life-saver @JoHoward!!! worked for me with some additions:

- also install **'python3-tk' and 'python3-dev'** with 'xfvb', as prompted by error logs in my github action
- run **pytest** instead of unittest

my full github action .yml:

```
name: Push
on: push

jobs:
  pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository # must checkout!
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4

      - name: Build environment
        run: pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

      - name: Pytest with pyautogui
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install xvfb python3-tk python3-dev
          xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x8" pytest -v
```